# How to restrict access to PC to one IP address

Tags: windows-7, networking, security

I'm wondering how best to go about this situation where I have a PC (running windows 7) which I am going to be using in an exhibition. I need the PC to be online so that it can push information to a web server, however, for security I only ever want one IP address (that of the webserver) to be able to connect to the PC. So I think I want to effectively set up a whitelist where only one IP can access port 80, does this sound right? Can anyone provide some advice on how to set this up securely?
Cheers in advance for any pointers!

Answer (score 6):

just use the windows7 firewall to limit access to some ports to a range of ips. look at http://hmcguirk.blogspot.com/2010/03/windows-7-firewall-limit-ssh-access-to.html to get an idea of how to do it.

http://maximumpcguides.com/windows-7/open-a-port-in-windows-7s-firewall/

Answer (score 0):

You could install a firewall on the PC and set very strict rules to only allow connections from one PC and block everything else.
Just search for free firewalls for windows in Google, I'm sure you'll find plenty of free ones. ZoneAlarm is the first I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

might be safer to configure a router to do the firewalling. It would get around any local OS hackers.